# Using Flavors to create different apk's using React Native and Android

Tags: android, gradle, react-native, android-productflavors, android-build-flavors

I am trying to create different APKs using flavors in an Android app written with React Native but I am getting the following error while running the `.gradlew assembleRelease` or any other combination:

```
Could not find method applicationIdSuffix() for arguments [.free] on ProductFlavor_Decorated{name=free, dimension=null, minSdkVersion=null, targetSdkVersion=null, renderscriptTargetApi=null, renderscriptSupportModeEnabled=null, renderscriptNdkModeEnabled=null, versionCode=null, versionName=null, applicationId=null, testApplicationId=null, testInstrumentationRunner=null, testInstrumentationRunnerArguments={}, testHandleProfiling=null, testFunctionalTest=null, signingConfig=null, resConfig=null, mBuildConfigFields={}, mResValues={}, mProguardFiles=[], mConsumerProguardFiles=[], mManifestPlaceholders={}}.
```

[image]

When I remove the `productFlavors` build process works correct.

`build.gradle` file looks like the following:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 27
        versionName "3.3.1"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
        free {
            applicationIdSuffix ".free"
        }
        pro {
            applicationIdSuffix ".pro"
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

The content of the `gradle-wrapper.properties` is as following:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.4-all.zip
```

Don't have any any clue what's wrong. Any idea what I am missing? Also I am using `Webstorm` as IDE cause I am working on a ReactNative Project and I mostly work on JS code, would things get easier especially about android configuration if I work with `AndroidStudio`

Thanks

Comment: if you run `gradlew tasks` you should see all the available tasks.  Normally you'd have `release` and `debug` entries under `buildTypes` and would then run something like `assembleFreeRelease`

Comment: Even `gradlew tasks` command gives the same error after adding productFlavors

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html#revisions  According to this, it says "You can now specify versionNameSuffix and applicationIdSuffix for product flavors. (Issue 59614)" for v2.14.1. Can you try updating the gradle in wrapper?

Answer (score 0):

Add resValue line to your "free" flavor

```
productFlavors {
        free {
            applicationIdSuffix ".free"
            resValue "string", "build_config_package", "com.your_package" // the package of your Android app
        }
        pro {
            applicationIdSuffix ".pro"
        }
    }
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just run

```
.gradlew assemblefreeRelease
```

it follows 'assemble[flavorsName]Release' pattern